# How to add contitions to Homeassistant App Widget?

Tags: android, home-assistant

I have a `homeassistant` android widget using the html template format:

```
<font color='blue'>{{ states('sensor.mystate') }}</font>
```

How can I change the color conditionally based on the value of the sensor?
Is it possible to add if/else conditions into the widget html template somehow?

Answer (score 1):

```
{% if states('sensor.mystate')|int > 75 -%}
  {% set color = 'green' %}
{%- else -%}
  {% set color = 'red' %}
{%- endif %}
{{ color }}

<font color='{{ color }}'>{{ states('sensor.mystate') }}</font>
```